# can't show all string values on x axis in AndroidPlot

Tags: android, string, androidplot

I can't show all string values on x axis in AndroidPlot

I  can show only 10 values from these 12 values :

String[]  Labels = {"Ahmed", "Mohammed", "tarek", "alaa", "mai","sahar", "fares",
   "adel","omar", "mahmoud","tamer","ali"};

alaa and omar not shown .

I use this code :

```
         private class GraphXLabelFormat extends Format {
    String[]  Labels = {"Ahmed", "Mohammed", "tarek", "alaa", "mai","sahar", "fares",
        "adel","omar", "mahmoud","tamer","ali"};

    @Override
   public StringBuffer format(Object object, StringBuffer buffer, FieldPosition field)     
     {
     int parsedInt =  Math.round(Float.parseFloat(object.toString()));
     String labelString = Labels[parsedInt];
      buffer.append(labelString);
      return buffer;
  }

  @Override
  public Object parseObject(String string, ParsePosition position) {
      return java.util.Arrays.asList(Labels).indexOf(string);
       }
   }
```

and in onCreate method I make :

```
       plot.getGraphWidget().setDomainValueFormat(new GraphXLabelFormat());
```

Answer (score 0):

*Originally answered in [this thread](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/androidplot/7S-sS5FajQk) but reposted here for convenience:*

Probably a rounding issue caused by an unequal number of points in your dataset and the size of labels[].  If you add some logging into your format(...) implementation like this, the problem should become obvious:

```
@Override
public StringBuffer format(Object object, StringBuffer buffer, FieldPosition field)     
     {
     Log.d(TAG, "raw input: " + object.toString());
     int parsedInt =  Math.round(Float.parseFloat(object.toString()));
     Log.d(TAG, "parsed input: " + parsedInt);

String labelString = Labels[parsedInt];
      buffer.append(labelString);
      return buffer;
}
```

Also this usage of toString() seems a little odd:

```
int parsedInt =  Math.round(Float.parseFloat(object.toString()));
```

Seems a little odd.  I'd suggest changing this line to:

```
int parsedInt =  Math.round(((Number) object).floatValue());
```